# Is "des" not needed after "de"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, noms

In the following sentence:

> Tu sais combien de secondes ça fait?

I thought "des" is needed before plural nouns (secondes), so at first I thought the following is correct:

> Tu sais combien de des secondes ça fait?

But this is not correct. So my questions are:

- Why is "des" not needed before "de"?
- In what case is it not needed? At first I thought it is not needed before a proposition, but is this correct?

---

I got more confused to see the following sentence (use of des, not de):

> Tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois.

In this case, *des*, not *de*, is used.

Answer (score 1):

**de+des** reduces to **de**. So, combien de+des secondes gives combien de secondes. See the lemma here

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/053.html

and here

http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/articles_leur_suppression.html

as well as an English language article

http://www.forum.french-linguistics.co.uk/forum/topics/when-to-use-only-de-instead-of-du-de-la-des

E.g.

> Je  voudrais  du  pain->J'ai besoin de pain.
>
> Je voudrais de l'argent->J'ai besoin d'argent (argent is a masculine word starting with a vowel).

But note the difference.

> J'ai besoin d'argent (besoin de+de la where de preposition and de la partitive article)

with

> J'ai besoin de l'argent que tu me dois.

Here (avoir besoin) de (preposition) + de la (definite article) gives de l' (du argent becomes de l'argent).

Comment: Thanks. So is the rule applicable only to "de" (possibly because the pronunciation is similar)?

Comment: @Blaszard  No. See the edited answer. E.g. Je  voudrais  du  pain->J'ai besoin de pain. Je voudrais de l'argent->J'ai besoin d'argent.

Comment: But note the difference. J'ai besoin d'argent (besoin de+de la where de preposition and de la partitive article) with...

Comment: J'ai besoin de l'argent que tu me dois. Here (avoir besoin) de (preposition) + de la (definite article) gives de l' (du argent becomes de l'argent).

Comment: @Blaszard I edited my answer. Tell me if it clear now. If the article in French is not comprehensible I will try to find an English one.

Comment: Thanks but I got confused to see *des* is also used. Could you check my edited question?

Comment: @Blaszard Can you show me the source of this sentence "Tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois"?

Comment: Although I don't have a justification right now, I don't think this *de* should be considered as a preposition in *combien de x*. I suspect should rather be considered the same as the indefinite article *de* that is found in negative sentences. Note to self: does it matter anyway?

Comment: @dimitris Sorry, I already lost the page but it is from a Duolingo French course. The course is created by native French speakers and English speakers who are fluent in French.

Comment: @Blaszard An Ngram shows that de deux mois is more frequently encountered than des deux mois. May be here its usage in "Tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois." is a standard one.

Comment: The Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+deux+mois%2C+de+deux+mois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20deux%20mois%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20deux%20mois%3B%2Cc0

Comment: « Des deux mois » et « de deux mois » sont corrects mais ne signifient jamais la même chose ; « Tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois  » signifie tous les mardis et mercredis de deux mois dont il vient d'être question dans le contexte ou dont il va être question; cela signifie que les deux mois sont déterminés; « des » est la contraction de « de les » et « les » est l'article défini déterminatif . Exemple : Tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois qui suivent seront consacrés à la lecture.

Comment: « Tous les mardis et mercredis de deux mois » signifie « tous les mardis et mercredis de deux mois quelconques, c'est à dire deux mois qui n'ont pas encore été spécifiés. Exemple : Tous les mardis et mercredis de deux mois dans l'année, préférablement de deux mois vers la fin de l'année, seront consacrés à la lecture. En anglais, cela donne pour le premier cas « All the tuesdays and wednesdays of (*or* in) the two months » and for the second « All tuesdays and wednesdays of  (*or* in) two months ».

Comment: Similarly: « J'ai peur de monstres » (I'm afraid of monsters) or « J'ai peur des monstres » (I'm afraid of monsters / of the monsters), but not « J'ai peur de des monstres ».

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it is related to quantity. According to [the this website](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/det8.html):

Example:

> When used with nouns, expressions of quantity are always followed by de (d' if the noun begins with a vowel sound).
>
> Tammy et Tex reçoivent des amis ce soir. Tammy est dans la cuisine. Tex regarde la télévision.
>
> Tammy: Une douzaine de crêpes, c'est trop pour quatre personnes?
>
> Tex: Mais non, Tammy, ce n'est pas assez. Il faut préparer beaucoup de crêpes.